# Why execute immediate is used here?

Tags: oracle, performance, plsql, dynamic-sql

I'm reading expert-oracle-database-architecture book. In this Tom is explaining about Bind Variables.

Can you please let me how first procedure is different from second procedure? 
As per my understanding we use `execute immediate` to execute a dynamic SQL statement or anonymous PL/SQL block.

Here is the target table:

```
create table t ( x int );
```

Here is example Procedure #1 :

```
ops$tkyte%ORA11GR2> create or replace procedure proc_name1
2 as
3 begin
4   for i in 1 .. 10
5     loop
6       execute immediate
7         'insert into t values ( '||i||')';
8   end loop;
9 end;
10 /
```

Here is example Procedure #2 :

```
create or replace procedure proc_name2
 as
 begin
   for i in 1 .. 10
   loop
     insert into t values ( i);
   end loop;
 end;
```

Comment: it's an example of what not to do

Comment: So there is no difference in both except the way they have written. Will there be any good performance using execute immediate?

Comment: It is an (ab)use of `execute immediate` statement. Also, strictly speaking, there is no need of a procedure for that simple insert at all, you could simply do it in pure SQL.

Comment: You should read the text around that for more information. Tom's telling you how many devs use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` for dynamic SQL without realizing how it kills performance, esp due to hard parsing of the statement for every loop iteration

Comment: Let's assume you do not know the table name `t` at design time and for some reason you have to do it in a loop instead of a single insert statement. In such case the statement would be better like `execute immediate 'insert into t values (:val)' USING i`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> "Will there be any good performance using execute immediate? "

The EXECUTE IMMEDIATE is what not to do. Its performance will be worse, because it does everything the non-dynamic example does, plus there's the overhead of hard parsing the statement for each iteration of the loop.

The point Tom is making is, inexperienced developers often use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (or other forms of dynamic SQL) when they don't need to. Dynamic SQL is bad news. Besides the performance impact:

- it is harder to write than static SQL
- syntax errors are runtime exceptions not compilation errors
- it is harder to maintain (impact analysis is tricky because dependencies don't appear in the data dictionary views).